# How to install Google maps on Android emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I have already installed all Google services and implemented them in my project.

But how about if I run my project which depends on Google maps service on an emulator?

Is there any way to install Google maps and Google services on an emulator?

Answer (score 1):

When you crate emulator, make sure you choose Google APIs as target.